# Interpretation of probability statements in Nina Zubrilina's paper

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

In the paper

https://content.sciendo.com/view/journals/dmgt/ahead-of-print/article-10.7151-dmgt.2210/article-10.7151-dmgt.2210.xml?language=en

The main result is

> $$\operatorname{edim}(G(n,p)) \leq (1+o(1))\frac{4 \log n}{\log(1/q)},$$ where $q= 1-2p(1-p)^2(2-p)$

My **first question** is how should I interpret the result, what is $\operatorname{edim}$ of random graph. Should I interpret it as

$$\mathbb{P} \left[ \operatorname{edim}(G(n,p)) \leq (1+o(1))\frac{4 \log n}{\log(1/q)} \right] \rightarrow 1 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty \text{ ?}$$

My second question is concerned with how to interpret lemma 2.2, it is stated that

> Let $G=G(n,p)$ be the random graph. Let $V,E$ denote the vertex and edge sets. Let $\omega \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$ be such that for any two distinct edges $e_1,e_2$ of $E$, a uniformly random subset $W \subset V$ of size $\omega$ satisfies
> $$\mathbb{P}( W \text{ does not distinguish } e_1,e_2) \leq 1/n^4p^2 $$
> Then
> $$\operatorname{edim}(G) \leq \omega$$

So, firstly how should I understand $E$ as subset of a random graph, and how can I fix two edges of this seemingly random set by saying "for any two distinct edges $e_1,e_2 \in E$". I am confused about how I interpret such statement. Can any one clarify them ?

Answer (score 1):

We could address your second question by saying that $G \sim G(n,p)$ is a random subgraph of the complete graph $K_n$ on some vertex set $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$, and considering the event "$W$ distinguises $e_1, e_2$" for $e_1, e_2 \in E(K_n)$ to be true automatically if $e_1, e_2$ are not both edges of $G$. This makes for a very reasonable interpretation. Also, when the diameter of $G(n,p)$ is $2$ (which is true with probability tending to $1$), the presence of edges $e_1, e_2$ in $G(n,p)$ will not affect distances from $W$ to their endpoints, except in the rare case that one of the endpoints is in $W$.

But then the thing that Lemma 2.2 actually proves is that if $G$ and $W$ are both randomly chosen, the expected number of pairs not distinguished is $\le \frac18$. This only proves that $$P(\operatorname{edim}(G) \le \omega) \ge \frac78$$ because it allows for the possibility that, for example, with probability $\frac18$ we get a $G$ such that *every* $W$ of size $\omega$ distinguishes all but one pair. So, if the hypotheses of Lemma 2.2 are met, then the main theorem should have a "with probability at least $\frac78$" at the end as well.

However, we can strengthen this result by making the analysis slightly more sophisticated. The expected value calculation also implies that
$$
   \mathbb P_{G \sim G(n,p)}(\text{every }W\text{ fails to distinguish }\log\log n\text{ pairs}) \le \frac1{8 \log\log n}
$$
so with probability tending to $1$, $G$ has a set $W$ of this size that distinguishes all but $\log\log n$ pairs of edges. But we can fix this by making $W$ slightly bigger: for example, for every pair $\{e_1, e_2\}$ that's not distinguished, add one of the endpoints of one of the edges to $W$. This bigger set still has size $(1+o(1))\frac{4\log n}{\log 1/q}$, because $\log\log n$ is a much smaller term, so the main theorem now holds with high probability.

Comment: I also have some uncertainties about other places where the paper is sloppy; for example, the independence assumptions involved in going from Lemma 2.4 to Lemma 2.2 or from Lemma 2.3 to Lemma 2.4. But in the end, those shouldn't change the conclusion, because almost everything is nearly independent, and cases that *aren't* independent (such as edges that share an endpoint) are actually distinguishable with a higher probability.